# Dspace 7 Angular, An error occurred while retrieving the browse definitions

Tags: angular, localhost, dspace

I have this problem, when I start DSpace Angular it takes time to load the page, the files are in localhost, the error that in the console is the following:

```
ERROR Error: An error occurred while retrieving the browse definitions.
    at BrowseResponseParsingService.deserialize (C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:695889)
    at BrowseResponseParsingService.process (C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:547982)
    at C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:550808
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BrowseResponseParsingService.processArray (C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:550771)
    at BrowseResponseParsingService.processPaginatedList (C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:550505)
    at BrowseResponseParsingService.process (C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:547824)
    at BrowseResponseParsingService.parse (C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:547026)
    at C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:379806
    at C:\dspace-angular\dist\server\main.js:1:4375777
```

What can I do about it to solve this problem?

I have tried to search among the configurations of the angular dspace, at times the local page loads and at times it does not load directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error. If you're able to access your DSpace HAL Browser and your DSpace UI, the problem is probably the connection to Solr. Make sure your Solr cores are in the correct location and owned by the solr user. If you're running solr 9+, be sure to follow directions on Bill's comment at the bottom of this page: https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/Installing+DSpace

Along the processes of fixing this error, I also had to make sure there was only one "Connector" element in my Tomcat server.xml file, AND I updated Solr from 9.2.0 to 9.2.1 and both the backend and frontend of DSpace, but I'm pretty sure Solr was the cause for this error.